# How to animate moving text on Manim

Tags: python, manim

I'm trying to learn Manim and I got a text that I wanna move around, the problem is, if only use text.to_edge(UP), the text just teleports, how do animate it to move smoothly?
Example:

```
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text = Text("something")
        self.play(Write(text))
        self.play(text.to_edge(UP))
```

When using   **self.play(Write(text))** the animation works fine, but when i try **self.play(text.to_edge(UP))** I get the error: `Unexpected argument Text('something') passed to Scene.play()`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
self.play(text.animate.to_edge(UP))
```

Source: https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/tutorials/building_blocks.html
Under "Animating methods"

Referencing the .animate property on any Mobject + the transformation you want to do. Animates the action if you pass it as an argument in a self.play() function.